# Is there any way for sync MySql function from kafka MySql source connector to kafka Oracle sink connector

Tags: mysql, oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm using kafka connector for CDC from MySQL to Oracle database.

It's my server specification.

```
- MySQL : 8.0
  - OS: centos 7.8(64-bit)
- Oracle : 18c xe
  - OS: Oracle Linux 7.6(64-bit)
- Source Connector : debezium-connector-mysql-1.9.5
- Sink Connector : confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.5.0
```

I have trying to sync different database MySQL and Oracle.

I have succeeded in `create table`, `insert` in MySQL and sync to oracle.
However, when function is created, topic is created by reading bin log, but it is not sink to Oracle.

When the confluent sink connector sinks data, it appears to be running SQL by referring to a table-based topic.
But when a function is generated, a separate topic other than the topic of the bin log is not generated, so the sink does not seem to be normal.
Is there any way to transfer the function of the database using CDC?